# FullCalendar AgendaWeek change color of week titles horizontal

Tags: css, fullcalendar

This seems like a simple question but I cannot find the attribute even after digging through the fullCalendar.css file.

Is there a way to change the text color and height of the box that has the highlighted "Sun Mon Tue Wed .." below?

[screenshot of highlighted "Sun Mon Tue Wed .."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVD1P.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this css:

```
.fc-day-header {
  background-color: red;
}
```

this is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ohpcdwtp/

Comment: Thanks so much @LakiGeri!